# Generate array of unique values in specific array column

Tags: php, arrays, unique, array-column

I'm getting the desired results back from my query and now I'm having trouble figuring 
out how to manipulate the data into something usable.

The ultimate goal is a json output to be used by google charts and I can do this on
any one single component without a problem.

I need the output to look like this (I have no idea how many components will come after 
Month/Year... it might be 0 or 10 or 20...):

```
      ['Month/Year', 'Wiper Blades', 'Mufflers'] [,[...]],
      ['March 2013',  13,      11],
      ['April 2013',  17,      19],
      [...],
      [...]
      ]);
```

Here is the array I have after my query ( can't do this in a while() because I need
the cmpnt_name for the first line of the desired output (above) which is why I'm building the array first):

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
      (
          [vmonth] => February
          [vyear] => 2013
          [cmpnt_count] => 9
          [cmpnt_name] => Wiper blade
      )

  [1] => Array
      (
          [vmonth] => March
          [vyear] => 2013
          [cmpnt_count] => 13
          [cmpnt_name] => Wiper blade
      )

  [2] => Array
      (
          [vmonth] => March
          [vyear] => 2013
          [cmpnt_count] => 11
          [cmpnt_name] => Muffler
      )

  [3] => Array
      (
          [vmonth] => April
          [vyear] => 2013
          [cmpnt_count] => 17
          [cmpnt_name] => Wiper blade
      )

  [4] => Array
      (
          [vmonth] => April
          [vyear] => 2013
          [cmpnt_count] => 19
          [cmpnt_name] => Muffler
      )
)
```

I can't loop through the array and take every cmpnt_name and append that to the 
first line of the desired output... I only want uniques.

Also a component may not have any views for a given month (it may not have even 
existed that month) so I may have components that date from Feb and other components 
that don't get added until later but are included in the count... i.e. Muffler was added
in March.

So how do I go about finding the unique component names for the first row?

I was thinking:

```
function findUniques($cmpnt)
{
  $names = array();
  foreach($cmpnt as $item)
  {
    $key = $item['cmpnt_name'];
    if(array_key_exists($key, $names))
    {
      $names[$key]++;
    }
    else
      $names[$key] = 1;
  }
  return($names);
}
```

Is there a php function for this?

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: would the array_unique() function help you get the unique names of components?

Comment: array_unique()... tried it, and too many nodes were unique because of month/year/count values

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do array_column, and then array unique, so try this:

```
array_unique(array_column($cmpnt, 'cmpnt_name'));
```

Comment: whoever downvoted, can you please explain why? I found this to work well for me, and was less complicated than the other answer below IMHO..

Comment: Note that `array_column` is new in PHP 5.5.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you would have some luck with `array_map` which allows you to extract all elements with a particular key. Example

```
Function compKey($v) {
    Return $v['cmpnt_name'];
}
CKeys = array_map("compKey", $cmpnt);
UniqueComponents = array_unique(CKeys);
```

Not sure syntax exactly right as typing this on iPhone, and don't know if more efficient. But worth a try?

Comment: + However, I consider this equivalent to the original code *refactored using array functions*. The simple answer is PHP currently can not do what is asked with a single function.

Comment: @jasonmccreary - I don't disagree. I thought it was a cool use of `array_map` though. I suspect there is no perceptible performance difference.

Comment: to me, it's the same issue... extract all the elements with the same key and you get all the elements.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a php function for this?

No. [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/array_unique) is the closest, but does not handle dimensional arrays.

> Is there a better way to do this?

Unfortunately, PHP (currently) does not have array functions that *pluck* keys into an array so you could then use `array_unique()`.

As such, short of some micro-optimizations or refactoring using array functions, what you have is generally what you have to do.

However, you do have typo:

```
$names[$key] = ++$count;
```

Comment: see my answer for the closest thing I could figure out for "pluck" function. Haven't figured out how to pass name of elect as second parameter, so hard coded it for this example - but it works.